# Is this "G" logo too complex for a website logo and mobile phone logo? How to improve color scheme?

Tags: logo, mobile, website-templates

1) Any suggestions how could I make it less complex, or is it OK?

2) Any suggestions how the color scheme be better? We want to emphasize we are global, and we are mainly targeting women, hence the salmon pink, but at the same time, we don't want to turn off men with a neon pink. How can we make it especially attractive for women, but still gender neutral?

small (slightly different colored but same thing):

[image]

big:

[image]

Comment: There's so much going on I don't know where to look.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the multiple blue/greens? Why the inverted G? Hard lines separating multiple objects, in general, aren't very feminine. And for many women, assuming pink *must* be used is actually kind of insulting. A lighter color palette isn't a bad thing for a female audience, but it doesn't *have* to be a pink the same way a mens product doesn't *have* to be a black.

Comment: May be try to turn G into a "negative space"? Making it's shape closer to a circle and filling with white. Then the outer contour of "G" could be stroked somehow.. Huh?

Comment: Worrying about the shade of pink and gender issues is perhaps worrying about minutia. I think you need to step back and work on the form a bit more before worrying too much about color. As for the logo, it's complex. Is it appropriate? Impossible to say without understanding your business and objectives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think this logo is to busy. The framework is pretty good, but the colors clash and the pattern on the G is makes it hard to read.

I first would like to say this is by no ways or means meant to be taken as an insult. I think this is a great start, it's clever and interesting and it has a really unique silhouette. I think it's gender neutral in it's current shape... maybe slightly masculine? Maybe you could try a sans serif smooth font or a handwritten one?

Ideally a logo should be clean and easy to denote when at the size of a favicon (16px x 16px or 32px x 32px). It's also good to try to keep the number of colors used down an absolute minimum. Although there are a large number of beautiful logos that don't follow this guideline (just look at [Instagram](http://instagram.com/)), it's a good thing to at least keep in mind.

A [few things to think about](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/26/vital-tips-for-effective-logo-design/) when making a logo could be, what your logo would look like if you only had 1 color to work with? What if it was all white on a colored background? What if it was small? Would it look good on a shirt? What about in print? Will it's silhouette look interesting?

As you try new things with a logo design, and if you don't really dig any of them, you can always go back to the drawing board, don't feel glued down to a design.

I think if your toned back the color, it would help a lot. The color scheme you're using isn't bad, I actually kinda like it, but the pink on dark green is to much of a clash, especially for small sizes. Don't try to mush in colors to try to appeal to different audiences, use shapes to do this instead. Keep the colors and use them all in the website.

If you take the pink out and make it a solid G, I think that would help. I also think if you used just one shade of blue / green / teal for the squares on the globe, it would help even further. Bellow I tried taking these things into consideration. I made everything the same color, messed with alpha values and gave the G a stroke because it was hard to see at small sizes.

[image]

I don't know how much you know about logos, so I just tried to spit up as much as I could about logo design. Some of it is just opinion, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome! Yours are much better. We will probably use something like that middle/left one. Much appreciated.

Comment: Complete answer and well done on actually producing proofs. The suggested design amendments mirror my sentiment with regards to the red overlay. Simply remove the said red and you'll have a conceptually decent and obvious symbol. The red is a case of going one step too far. Though the author of the question provided a "small" proof, "small", in my mind, is a 16px x 16px favicon.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very ambiguous question. The logo has too much things to improve. It has too much targets:

- Women
- At the same time Men
- At the same time Neutral
- Global

  I recommend to search for a professional graphic designer consultation.

Comment: Welcome Mike! While self-promotion is fine for your profile page, it is not something which belongs in any answer. I've removed the self-promo aspect of this answer.